# Como realizar un SELECT con tres tablas en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datatables, subconsultas

Quiero realizar un SELECT entre tres tablas, las tres tablas son las siguientes.

```
empleadosSL
  idEmpleado
  nomina
  nombre

empleadoSP
  idEmpleado
  nomina
  nombre

Resguardo
  folio
  fecha
  nomina
  observaciones
  status
```

Anteriormente tenia una vista con el siguiente SELECT:

```
SELECT hr.folio, hr.fecha, hr.nomina, hr.observaciones, sl.nombre
FROM dbo.Resguardo AS hr INNER JOIN 
dbo.empleadosSL AS sl ON hr.nomina = sl.nomina
WHERE hr.status = 1
```

cabe mencionar que la tabla empleadosSL realmente es una vista de otra tabla en otra base de datos, cree la tabla empleadosSP por que hay se registraran otro tipo de empleados que no pueden ser registrados en empleadosSL, a lo que quiero llegar es que el SELECT me arroje el resultado de la vista anterior pero esta vez añadiendo la tabla empleadosSP intente con:

```
SELECT hr.folio, hr.fecha, hr.nomina, hr.observaciones, sl.nombre
FROM dbo.Resguardo AS hr INNER JOIN 
dbo.empleadosSL AS sl ON hr.nomina = sl.nomina INNER JOIN
dbo.empleadosSP as sp ON hr.nomina = sp.nomina
WHERE hr.status = 1
```

pero no me arrojo ningún registro ya que las nominas entre empleadosSL y empleadosSP no se repiten, también intente con

```
SELECT hr.folio, hr.fecha, hr.nomina, hr.observaciones, sl.nombre
FROM dbo.Resguardo AS hr INNER JOIN 
dbo.empleadosSL AS sl ON hr.nomina = sl.nomina or 
hr.nomina = dbo.empleadosSP.nomina
WHERE hr.status = 1
```

pero me marca el error:  the muliti-part "d.nomina" could not be bound

Answer (score 0):

Si todos son empleados, lo primero que puedo decir es que no es el diseño más limpio. Para comenzar, no puedes tener una llave foránea desde otras partes del modelo que hagan referencia a un empleado a ninguna de las tablas de `empleado`-x, y las opciones son mantener la integridad sin reglas declarativas es un reto bastante grande, o duplicar el resto de la estructura, lo cual tampoco es muy deseable.

En fin, dejando atrás ese tema, lo que tu necesitas es hacer *join* de la tabla de Resguardo con la *unión* de las tablas de empleados.  Puedes hacerlo directamente en la consulta:

```
select hr.folio, hr.fecha, hr.nomina, hr.observaciones, e.nombre
  from Resguardo hr
       inner join (select *
                     from empleadoSL
                   union all
                   select *
                     from empleadoSP
                  ) e 
               on e.nomina = hr.nomina
```

O bien, hacer una vista que una los registros de ambas tablas:

```
create view vwEmpleadoTodos as
select *
  from empleadoSL
union all
select *
  from empleadoSP
```

Y simplificar la consulta final:

```
select hr.folio, hr.fecha, hr.nomina, hr.observaciones, e.nombre
  from Resguardo hr
       inner join vwEmpleadoTodos e on e.nomina = hr.nomina
```